# How to build bullet (hit) damage detection in Augmented Reality to a real life person acting as an opponent?

Tags: collision-detection, android, first-person-shooter, augmented-reality

I am building an Android AR game using ARcore 1.18 in Unity 2019.4.5f1 (LTS). Now I want to create something like bullet damage detection just like it is built in a normal Unity 3D game.

Of course, the biggest problem is how can I even detect the real person's hitbox like it is done in a normal game? I need to somehow be able to attach the bullet damage script to the body of the real-life person in real-time.

Has anyone tried this before? How can we achieve this? I understand if I might not get a spoonfed tutorial but some help towards what should I be doing to achieve this will be greatly appreciated.

I see some other FPS Augmented Reality games which either uses Laser Tag (Father.io) or Barcodes to scan the opponents. These are definitely some great ideas to create an FPS game experience but still, if possible, I want to try it with just the mobile camera without any external support. I am ready to bear some accuracy loss :)

Comment: Ate you able to get estimated joint positions from.your AR library? When I'd dome this with Kinect in the past, I set up box or capsule colliders spanning the line segments between the joints, repositioning them each frame with the latest info.

Comment: @DMGregory I searched about that but I couldn't find any way to get joint positions through ARCore, probably because Android phones don't come with as good sensors as Kinect's. Actually, body tracking is quite simply possible through ARKit, which is the library that supports AR in IOS devices. But ARCore doesn't support anything like that directly :(

Comment: Sounds like you'll need to locate a body tracking library to use then, as this kind of computer vision problem is much too thorny yo fit into an answer here.

Comment: I get that. Thanks for your help.